# Android Program Hangs After Click

Tags: android, freeze

I'm writing an android app that quizzes me on drink recipes through multiple choice. After a choice is pressed, the app colors the correct answer and produces a new question. After some number of rounds however, it hangs and I can't find why. I posted the code and layout below.

```
package com.example.frances.rocksdrinks;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;


public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] allDrinks = {"BOURBON ON THE ROCKS", "SCOTCH ON THE ROCKS", "TOP SHELF SCOTCH ON THE ROCKS", "BLACK RUSSIAN", "SICILIAN KISS",
        "GOD MOTHER", "GOD FATHER", "RUSTY NAIL", "NUTTY IRISHMAN", "STINGER", "KAMIKAZE", "PURPLE HOOTER", "WINDEX",
        "RASPBERRY KAMIKAZE", "MUDSLIDE", "AFTER FIVE", "B~51", "B~52", "B~53", "OATMEAL COOKIE"};

Map<String, String> liquor = new HashMap<String, String>()
{{
    put("bourbon on the rocks", "1 1/2 oz Bourbon Whiskey");
    put("scotch on the rocks", "1 1/2 oz Scotch Whiskey");
    put("top shelf scotch on the rocks", "1 1/2 oz Scotch Whiskey");
    put("black russian", "1 1/4 oz Vodka & 3/4 oz Kahlua");
    put("sicilian kiss", "1 1/4 oz Southern Comfort & 3/4 oz Amaretto");
    put("god mother", "1 1/4 oz Vodka & 3/4 oz Amaretto");
    put("god father", "1 1/4 oz Scotch & 3/4 oz Amaretto");
    put("rusty nail", "1 1/4 oz Scotch & 3/4 oz Drambuie");
    put("Nutty Irishman", "1 1/4 oz Baileys & 3/4 oz Frangelico");
    put("stinger", "1 1/4 oz Brandy & 3/4 oz White Creme De Menthe");
    put("kamikaze", "1 1/4 oz Vodka & 3/4 oz Triple Sec");
    put("purple hooter", "1 1/4 oz Vodka & 3/4 oz Chambord");
    put("windex", "1 1/4 oz Vodka & 3/4 oz Blue Curacao");
    put("raspberry kamikaze", "1 1/4 oz Raspberry Vodka & 3/4 oz Triple Sec");
    put("mudslide", "1/2 oz Kahlua & 1/2 oz Baileys & 1/2 oz Vodka");
    put("after five", "1/2 oz Kahlua & 1/2 oz Baileys & 1/2 oz Peppermint Schnapps");
    put("b~51", "1/2 oz Kahlua & 1/2 oz Baileys & 1/2 oz Frangelico");
    put("b~52", "1/2 oz Kahlua & 1/2 oz Baileys & 1/2 oz Grand Marnier");
    put("b~53", "1/2 oz Kahlua & 1/2 oz Baileys & 1/2 oz Amaretto");
    put("oatmeal cookie", "1/2 oz Kahlua & 1/2 oz Baileys & 1/2 oz Goldschlager");
}};

Map<String, String> mixer = new HashMap<String, String>()
{{
    put("bourbon on the rocks", "");
    put("scotch on the rocks", "");
    put("top shelf scotch on the rocks", "");
    put("black russian", "");
    put("sicilian kiss", "");
    put("god mother", "");
    put("god father", "");
    put("rusty nail", "");
    put("Nutty Irishman", "");
    put("stinger", "");
    put("kamikaze", "");
    put("purple hooter", "");
    put("windex", "");
    put("raspberry kamikaze", "");
    put("mudslide", "");
    put("after five", "");
    put("b~51", "");
    put("b~52", "");
    put("b~53", "");
    put("oatmeal cookie", "");
}};

Map<String, String> garnish = new HashMap<String, String>()
{{
    put("bourbon on the rocks", "None");
    put("scotch on the rocks", "None");
    put("top shelf scotch on the rocks", "None");
    put("black russian", "None");
    put("sicilian kiss", "None");
    put("god mother", "None");
    put("god father", "None");
    put("rusty nail", "Lemon Twist");
    put("Nutty Irishman", "None");
    put("stinger", "Mint Leaf");
    put("kamikaze", "Splash Lime Juice");
    put("purple hooter", "Splash Lime Juice");
    put("windex", "Splash Lime Juice");
    put("raspberry kamikaze", "Splash Lime Juice");
    put("mudslide", "None");
    put("after five", "None");
    put("b~51", "None");
    put("b~52", "None");
    put("b~53", "None");
    put("oatmeal cookie", "None");
}};

Random r = new Random();

TextView choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, answer, question;
String ans;
int qIndex;
String[] choices;
TextView correct;
Handler handler;

TextView pressed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    choice1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    choice2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    choice3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    choice4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice4);

    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);

    handler = new Handler();

    createQuestion();
    createAnswers();

    question.setTextSize(21);
}

public void choice(View v)
{
    pressed = (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
    answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (pressed.getText().toString() == choices[0])
    {
        pressed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00BF00"));
        answer.setText("CORRECT!");
        answer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00BF00"));
    }
    else
    {
        pressed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F60000"));
        answer.setText("WRONG!");
        answer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F60000"));
        correct.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00BF00"));
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pressed.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
            correct.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
            answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            createQuestion();
            createAnswers();
        }
    }, 3000);

}

//if answer is a recipe, use 20sp as font size
private void createQuestion()
{
    String[] qs = {"Which drink contains ", "What garnish does drink contain", "What mixer does drink use",
            "Which of the following describes a drink"};


    int i = r.nextInt(allDrinks.length);
    ans = allDrinks[i];

    qIndex = r.nextInt(qs.length);
    String q = "";

    if (qIndex != 0)
    {
        q = qs[qIndex].replace("drink", ans);
    }
    else
    {
        q = qs[qIndex] + liquor.get(ans.toLowerCase());

        if (!mixer.get(ans.toLowerCase()).isEmpty())
        {
            q += " + " + mixer.get(ans.toLowerCase());;
        }

        if (!garnish.get(ans.toLowerCase()).equals("None"))
        {
            q += " + " + garnish.get(ans.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    question.setText(q + "?");
}

private void createAnswers()
{
    choices = new String[4];
    int count = 1;
    String a = "";

    if (qIndex == 3)
    {
        choices[0] = liquor.get(ans.toLowerCase());
        if (!mixer.get(ans.toLowerCase()).isEmpty())
        {
            choices[0] += ", " + mixer.get(ans.toLowerCase());
        }

        if (!garnish.get(ans.toLowerCase()).equals("None"))
        {
            choices[0] += ", " + garnish.get(ans.toLowerCase());
        }

        while (count != 4)
        {
            int i = r.nextInt(allDrinks.length);
            if (allDrinks[i] != ans)
            {
                a = liquor.get(allDrinks[i].toLowerCase());

                if (!mixer.get(ans.toLowerCase()).isEmpty())
                {
                    a += ", " + mixer.get(allDrinks[i].toLowerCase());
                }

                if (!garnish.get(allDrinks[i].toLowerCase()).equals("None"))
                {
                    a += ", " + garnish.get(allDrinks[i].toLowerCase());
                }

                if (!Arrays.asList(choices).contains(a))
                {
                    choices[count] = a;
                    count++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else if (qIndex == 0)
    {
        choices[0] = ans;

        while (count != 4)
        {
            int i = r.nextInt(allDrinks.length);
            if (allDrinks[i] != ans)
            {
                a = allDrinks[i];

                if (!Arrays.asList(choices).contains(a))
                {
                    choices[count] = a;
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    else if (qIndex == 1)
    {
        String[] g = {"Splash Coke", "Splash Grenadine", "Splash Sprite", "None"};
        choices[0] = garnish.get(ans.toLowerCase());

        while (count != 4)
        {
            int i = r.nextInt(g.length);
            if (g[i] != choices[0])
            {
                a = g[i];

                if (!Arrays.asList(choices).contains(a))
                {
                    choices[count] = a;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        choices[0] = mixer.get(ans.toLowerCase());

        while (count != 4)
        {
            int i = r.nextInt(allDrinks.length);
            if (mixer.get(allDrinks[i].toLowerCase()) != choices[0])
            {
                a = mixer.get(allDrinks[i].toLowerCase());
                if (!Arrays.asList(choices).contains(a))
                {
                    choices[count] = a;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    TextView[] cs = {choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4};
    cs = shuffle(cs);
    correct = cs[0];

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (qIndex == 3)
        {
            cs[i].setTextSize(12);
        }
        else
        {
            cs[i].setTextSize(18);
        }
        cs[i].setText(choices[i]);
    }
}

private TextView[] shuffle(TextView[] arr)
{
    int index;
    TextView temp;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

}

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="140sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="Which drink contains 1/2 oz Jagermeister1/2 oz Peach Schnapps + Cranberry Juice"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadowsmall"
        android:layout_width="180sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:text="Screwdriver"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="choice"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadowsmall"
        android:layout_width="180sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:text="Screwdriver"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="choice"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice3"
        android:layout_marginTop="130sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadowsmall"
        android:layout_width="180sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:text="Screwdriver"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="choice"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice4"
        android:layout_marginTop="130sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadowsmall"
        android:layout_width="180sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:text="1 oz vodka, 50/50 orange and cranberry, lime"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:onClick="choice"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="-40sp"
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat gives this output when it starts hanging

```
03-28 12:51:05.460 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.490ms
03-28 12:51:15.605 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14222(509KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1825KB/2MB, paused 5.062ms total 11.585ms
03-28 12:51:23.159 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 10.660ms for cause Background
03-28 12:52:48.768 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.314ms
03-28 12:52:58.857 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 30454(1094KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 1708KB/2MB, paused 5.259ms total 13.447ms
03-28 12:54:07.970 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.891ms
03-28 12:54:24.523 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.254ms
03-28 12:54:45.569 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.900ms
03-28 12:54:49.078 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.536ms
03-28 12:54:57.595 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.742ms
03-28 12:55:30.525 29897-29912/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.450ms for cause HeapTrim
03-28 12:55:34.194 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.670ms
03-28 12:55:56.904 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.412ms
03-28 12:56:09.293 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.397ms
03-28 12:56:37.481 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 29570(1064KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 1688KB/2MB, paused 10.745ms total 18.296ms
03-28 12:56:42.810 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.896ms
03-28 12:57:03.446 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.611ms
03-28 12:57:10.750 29897-29912/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 9.071ms for cause HeapTrim
03-28 12:57:38.029 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.944ms
03-28 12:57:45.548 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.624ms
03-28 12:58:00.093 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.481ms
03-28 12:58:10.900 29897-29912/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.327ms for cause HeapTrim
03-28 12:59:42.489 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.841ms
03-28 13:00:01.148 29897-29912/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 6.726ms for cause HeapTrim
03-28 13:00:18.072 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26985(971KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 35% free, 1757KB/2MB, paused 6.471ms total 14.159ms
03-28 13:00:21.155 29897-29912/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.892ms for cause HeapTrim
03-28 13:00:41.162 29897-29912/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 5.154ms for cause HeapTrim
03-28 13:02:48.702 29897-29908/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.836ms
03-28 13:02:53.694 29897-29913/com.example.frances.rocksdrinks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.996ms
```

I haven't been able to find out what's wrong from my code. This is currently the only activity in the app. Thank you.

UPDATE:
I found that if I remove the createAnswers function, it stops hanging but I haven't figured out why it causes the hang.

SOLVED: 
Turns out since rocks drinks don't have a mixer (all entries in the mixer hashmap is an empty string), it affects the else statement in createAnswers where I create answers for the mixer question. I don't know why it created memory leaks though but I removed it and now it works fine.

Comment: why do you need a Handler?

Comment: The handler is so that the screen pauses for 3 seconds so that the user can see the correct answer before updating to a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Make the Handler static it's causing memory leaks :

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

Comment: I've tried making the handler static and removing the handler entirely but it still hangs.

Comment: Assuming the choices is fixed size could you new up the array at the top where you declare it choices = new String[4]; in your createAnswers() methods see if this makes a difference? you can clean up the array at the end of the method like this : Arrays.fill(choices , 0);

Comment: Hey Chester, I found the problem and wrote it at the end of my question. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: No problem in future rather save all the questions, answers and the data in HashMaps in a file or use https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html,

Answer (score 0):

You should check the while loop inside the createAnswers function , does it ends every time at acceptable time or takes a long time because count++ is inside a condition that may not be fulfilled